# Import an HTML file into an other HTML file

Tags: html, django, include

I would like to know how to import an HTML file into an other HTML file.

Both files refer to a lot of different files, so I would prefer to keep them into two different folders instead of copying one file into the other.

---

For now, I'm developing locally, with Django.

Comment: Have you considered using PHP? `<? include('something.php'); ?>`

Comment: or JSP? `<jsp:include ... />`

Comment: Thanls for your answers. But I'm sorry, I'm new with programming so I don't really get it. I can use php language in my html file without importing anything? And I can rename my html file with '.php' without any problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`{% include 'file.html' %}` should work

Comment: as Wezly mentioned it, read the docs. Maybe the `{% block %}` tag could be useful to you someday too.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used Django before, but they have documentation on their template language here.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure of the question but [this](http://webdesign.about.com/od/ssi/a/aa052002a.htm) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Including pages with only HTML:

```
<!--#include virtual="pagetoinclude.html" -->
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I tried like this: <!--#include virtual="/Users/marc-antoinelacroix/Desktop/test.html" -->   and nothing appears. Is it a problem with the path? Do I have to put it in a specific section (head, body...). thank you